# How to generate Envers database schema with org.hibernate.tool.EnversSchemaGenerator?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I updated Hibernate to the 4.1.1.Final version. According to [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d5e3883) 
There are 2 ways to generate a database schema:

1. Ant task `org.hibernate.tool.ant.EnversHibernateToolTask`.
2. Run `org.hibernate.tool.EnversSchemaGenerator` from Java.

Hibernate-tools doesn't work with Hibernate-4.1.1.Final. It has a [blocking bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-10736?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel).

I found only [release notes](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateORM411Release) and a [test case](https://fisheye2.atlassian.com/changelog/Hibernate-Core?cs=7c60f01f2d5e5dd40d4f2edb0ef3339c803a7560).
So how can I use `org.hibernate.tool.EnversSchemaGenerator` with my persistence.xml and Maven?

**Update:**

Found related [thread on the Hibernate forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1014593). It seems there is no answer to my question yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Juplo has created [Maven plugin for Hibernate 4](http://juplo.de/hibernate4-maven-plugin/index.html). The plugin supports schema export including Envers. The working example is below. Check [official plugin configuration documentation](http://juplo.de/hibernate4-maven-plugin/export-mojo.html) to get explanation for used options.

The plugin generates `schema.sql` file in the Maven `/target` directory on `test` goal.
Or you can manually run `hibernate4:export` goal to update the file.

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.juplo</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>export</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <envers>true</envers>
                    <format>true</format>
                    <delimiter>;</delimiter>
                    <force>true</force>
                    <type>CREATE</type>
                    <target>SCRIPT</target>
                    <hibernateDialect>org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</hibernateDialect>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its very easy.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need Ant or Hibernate tools. It's pretty easy to just use the EnversSchemaGenerator directly, like this:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();

//make sure you set the dialect correctly for your database (oracle for example below)
config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");

//add all of your entities
config.addAnnotatedClass(MyAnnotatedEntity.class);

SchemaExport export = new EnversSchemaGenerator(config).export();
export.execute(true, false, false, false);
```

You can also give it a file name to write to, but the code above will print to the syslog anyway.

Comment: is it typo? There is no EnversSchemaGeneHator.class in hibernate doc but there is  EnversSchemaGenerator.class

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ejb3Configuration jpaConfiguration = new Ejb3Configuration().configure("persistenceUnit", null);
    jpaConfiguration.buildMappings();
    Configuration hibernateConfiguration = jpaConfiguration.getHibernateConfiguration();
    AuditConfiguration.getFor(hibernateConfiguration);
    EnversSchemaGenerator esg = new EnversSchemaGenerator(hibernateConfiguration);
    org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport se = esg.export();
    se.setOutputFile("sql/schema.sql");
    se.setFormat(true);
    se.setDelimiter(";");
    se.drop(true, false);
    se.create(true, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem. Now there is a Hibernate 4 Tools version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-CR1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But this Ant fragment does not export the audit tables, only the "basic" tables:

```
<target name="schema-export">
    <taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.EnversHibernateToolTask" classpathref="classpath"/>
    <hibernatetool destdir="sql">
        <classpath refid="classpath"/>
        <jpaconfiguration persistenceunit="persistenceUnit"/>
        <hbm2ddl export="false" create="true" drop="true" format="true" outputfilename="schema.sql"/>
    </hibernatetool>
</target>
```

Same with this code: Only "basic", no "_aud" tables:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ejb3Configuration jpaConfiguration = new Ejb3Configuration().configure("persistenceUnit", null);
    Configuration hibernateConfiguration = jpaConfiguration.getHibernateConfiguration();
    AuditConfiguration.getFor(hibernateConfiguration);
    EnversSchemaGenerator esg = new EnversSchemaGenerator(hibernateConfiguration);
    org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport se = esg.export();
    se.setOutputFile("sql/schema.sql");
    se.setFormat(true);
    se.setDelimiter(";");
    se.drop(true, false);
    se.create(true, false);
}
```

Are you still interested? I'll let you know if I find out how to solve the problem. Maybe somebody else has got any advice for us?

Comment: Check my answer on this question. I've found the most convenient way to complete the task.