# EnversSchemaGenerator cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to generate database schema according to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17844417/9608756

but eclipse doesn't recognize class `EnversSchemaGenerator`. There is no automatic import for this class and can't see it in my jars.

This is script:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");

config.addAnnotatedClass(MyClass.class);

SchemaExport export = new EnversSchemaGenerator(config).export(); // ERROR!
```

This is pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-envers -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample you're trying to use is based on an older version of the Hibernate. The `EnversSchemaGenerator` class has been removed from Hibernate source (issue [HHH-11461](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11461)).

You can use the `SchemaExport` class as mentioned in [Programmatically Generating Database Schema with Hibernate 5](https://shekhargulati.com/2018/01/09/programmatically-generating-database-schema-with-hibernate-5/).

Comment: Under the hood, EnversSchemaGenerator was using `SchemaExport` class.

Comment: will SchemaExport generate the Envers tables too?

Comment: i wrote a driver program to instantiate and execute the SchemaExport class and it does indeed create the audit tables provided that the classes are adorned with the @Audited annotation.